# How to edit `cell[i]` in data grid view C# win form without button and textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

On a winform, I have used the editor to bind a data grid view to a SQL Server database. The Data Source created the following objects: Binding Source, Table Adapter, Table Adapter Manager, and a Binding Navigator. My goal is simply to read the information from SQL Server table [getdata], allow some editing, and to pass the information to Database table [newdata];. Additionally, I added  unbound columns to the view. So, there are  'bound' columns and  unbound columns. When I run the application, the data is there. However, I cannot edit any of the cells (  unbound ). The grid view read-only property is set to false. The column read-only property are set to false.

my code for datagridview is :

```
private void btnCalcSeason3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cnn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter($@"
            SELECT
                Id
                , Tid
                , NAME
                , OfferedAmount
                , BondNum
                , BondValue
                , BondDate
                , BondBank
                , FinancialIndex
                , CASE
                    WHEN FinancialIndex > {Convert.ToDouble(txtLcl.Text)} THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END AS LCL
                , CASE
                    WHEN FinancialIndex < {Convert.ToDouble(txtUcl.Text)} THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END AS Ucl
                , CASE
                    WHEN FinancialIndex > {Convert.ToDouble(txtLcl.Text)}
                        AND FinancialIndex < {Convert.ToDouble(txtUcl.Text)} THEN
                    'داخل'
                    ELSE 'خارج'
                    END AS luresult
                , IsDelete
                , DeleteDisc
                , CASE
                    WHEN FinancialIndex > {Convert.ToDouble(txtLcl.Text)}
                        AND FinancialIndex < {Convert.ToDouble(txtUcl.Text)} THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END AS valresult
                , CASE
                    WHEN
                        FinancialIndex > {Convert.ToDouble(txtLcl.Text)}
                        AND FinancialIndex < {Convert.ToDouble(txtUcl.Text)}
                    THEN 'پذیرش'
                    ELSE 'حذف'
                    END AS sresult
                , CASE
                    WHEN FinancialIndex < {Convert.ToDouble(txtLcl.Text)} THEN 'حذف - فصل سوم - ماده 9 - فاقد صحت مبانی قیمت و غیرقابل اجرا'
                    WHEN FinancialIndex > {Convert.ToDouble(txtUcl.Text)} THEN 'حذف - فصل سوم - ماده 10 - فاقد صحت مبانی قیمت و غیرقابل اجرا'
                    WHEN 
                        FinancialIndex < {Convert.ToDouble(txtLcl.Text)}
                        AND FinancialIndex > {Convert.ToDouble(txtUcl.Text)}
                    THEN 'حذف - فصل سوم - ماده 9و10 - فاقد صحت مبانی قیمت و غیرقابل اجرا'
                    ELSE ''
                END  AS decription
        FROM Bidder
        WHERE tid = {frmDomain.ID}", cnn);
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    dgSeason3.DataSource = dt;
    dt.Columns.Add("chbCommittee", typeof(bool), "valresult");
    dt.Columns.Add("result", typeof(string), "sresult");
    dt.Columns.Add("discreason", typeof(string), "decription");
    cnn.Close();
    dgSeason3.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["Tid"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["Name"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    dgSeason3.Columns["Name"].HeaderText = "نام شرکت ";
    dgSeason3.Columns["OfferedAmount"].Width = 135;
    dgSeason3.Columns["OfferedAmount"].HeaderText = "مبلغ پیشنهادی";
    dgSeason3.Columns["FinancialIndex"].Width = 110;
    dgSeason3.Columns["FinancialIndex"].HeaderText = "شاخص مالی ";
    dgSeason3.Columns["Lcl"].Width = 120;
    dgSeason3.Columns["Lcl"].HeaderText = "بررسی حد پایین ";
    dgSeason3.Columns["Ucl"].Width = 120;
    dgSeason3.Columns["Ucl"].HeaderText = "بررسی حد بالا";
    dgSeason3.Columns["luresult"].Width = 120;
    dgSeason3.Columns["luresult"].HeaderText = "بررسی محدوده";
    dgSeason3.Columns["chbCommittee"].Width = 120;
    dgSeason3.Columns["chbCommittee"].HeaderText = "نظر کمیته فنی";
    dgSeason3.Columns["result"].Width = 120;
    dgSeason3.Columns["result"].HeaderText = "وضعیت";
    dgSeason3.Columns["discreason"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    dgSeason3.Columns["discreason"].HeaderText = "توضیحات";
    dgSeason3.Columns["IsDelete"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["DeleteDisc"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["BondNum"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["BondValue"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["BondDate"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["BondBank"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["valresult"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["sresult"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["decription"].Visible = false;
    dgSeason3.Columns["OfferedAmount"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = ("#,0");
    dgSeason3.Columns["BondValue"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = ("#,0");
    dgSeason3.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injection. I suggest you use [`AddWithValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead.

Comment: @GeomanYabes - never use AddWithValue: [1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderPetrov. That's some interesting articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding incorrect column name to the grid columns.

You are using [`DataTable.Columns.Add(string? columnName, Type type, string expression)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.add?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataColumnCollection_Add_System_String_System_Type_System_String_) overload:

```
dt.Columns.Add("chbCommittee", typeof(bool), "valresult");
dt.Columns.Add("result", typeof(string), "sresult");
dt.Columns.Add("discreason", typeof(string), "decription");
```

The column names should be `"chbCommittee"`, `"result"`, and `"discreason"` but you have been using the `"Expression"` in your grids:

```
dgSeason3.Columns["valresult"].Visible = false;
dgSeason3.Columns["sresult"].Visible = false;
dgSeason3.Columns["decription"].Visible = false;
```

To fix:

```
dgSeason3.Columns["chbCommittee"].Visible = false;
dgSeason3.Columns["result"].Visible = false;
dgSeason3.Columns["discreason"].Visible = false;
```

Additional:

As mentioned in the comment, your code is prone to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [`AddWithValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead (or [SqlParameterCollection.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) due to problems with `AddWithValue` as stated by @AlexanderPetrov in his comment.):

Your code would also be cleaner if you have a list of models instead and then bind that `List<BidderModels>` into your `dgSeason3.DataSource`:

```
public class BidderModel {
    public string Id { get; set; } //change `string` into whatever data type your `Id` column is
    public string Tid { get; set; } //change `string` into whatever data type your `Tid` column is
    // . . . . your "bound" columns
   // . . . . your "unbound" columns

}
```

Then you can use the above model like below:

```
private void btnCalcSeason3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cnn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter($@"your query", cnn);
    adapt.Fill(dt);

    cnn.Close();

    List<BidderModel> bidders = new List<BidderModel>();
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)  // dt is a DataTable
    {
        bidders.Add(new BidderModel() {
            Id = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()),
            Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
            // . . . and so on and so forth
        });
    }

    dgSeason3.DataSource = bidders;
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you 
i changed my code to public class BidderModel... but i still can't edit currentrow.columns[5]
i need edit this column and after edit another column value changed aoutomatically

Comment: @abbas, what do you mean _"edit `currentrow.columns[5]`"_? Where are you editing?

Comment: Thank you so much this code work but when i want edit one cell of column[5] i have to chang all of grid view to read only false but i want just change read only of column [5] to false